# Log4net rolling file with custom filename

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

1. We want to create only 4 log files, If count of log file is increased then oldest log file should be deleted and other will get renamed.
2. After every hour log file name should be changed with previous hour
3. After day log file name should be changed with previous day
   and new file name should always same

example :

---

```
Time 01-11-2019 10:00
Log file name - abc.log
Log file size - 10kb
```

---

```
Time 01-11-2019 10:20
Log file name - abc.log
Log file size - 11kb
old Log file name - abc.log.1
old Log file size - 10kb
```

---

```
Time 01-11-2019 10:45
Log file name - abc.log
Log file size - 12kb
old Log file name - abc.log.1
old Log file size - 11kb
old Log file name - abc.log.2
old Log file size - 10kb
```

---

```
Time 01-11-2019 10:50
Log file name - abc.log
Log file size - 13kb
old Log file name - abc.log.1
old Log file size - 12kb
old Log file name - abc.log.2
old Log file size - 11kb
old Log file name - abc.log.3
old Log file size - 10kb
```

---

### **Now if new file is created then oldest should be delete and other will get renamed like below**

```
Time 01-11-2019 10:55
Log file name - abc.log
Log file size - 14kb
old Log file name - abc.log.1
old Log file size - 13kb
old Log file name - abc.log.2
old Log file size - 12kb
old Log file name - abc.log.3
old Log file size - 11kb

(log file with size 10kb get deleted)
```

---

**Now if hour get changed file name should be in (yyyyMMddHH) like below**

---

```
Time 01-11-2019 11.10
Log file name - abc.log
Log file size - 15kb
old Log file name - abc.log.2019110110.1
old Log file size - 14kb
old Log file name - abc.log.2019110110.2
old Log file size - 13kb
old Log file name - abc.log.2019110110.3
old Log file size - 12kb

(log file with size 11kb get deleted)
```

---

**Now if date get changed file name should be in (yyyyMMdd) like below**

---

```
Time 02-11-2018 11.10
Log file name - abc.log
Log file size - 16kb
old Log file name - abc.log.20191101.1
old Log file size - 15kb
old Log file name - abc.log.20191101.2
old Log file size - 14kb
old Log file name - abc.log.20191101.3
old Log file size - 13kb

(log file with size 12kb get deleted)
```

---

How is this possible with log4net?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

we can create a RollingFileAppender to take the backup of files every day and max of 4 files. We can configure either to take the backup daily or hourly but not both .Change the `DatePattern` based on your requirement Below is the sample configuration

```
 <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
         <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="4" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```